# bound the norm of a L2 function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X, \mu)$ be a $\sigma $-finite measure space, $f $ be a $L^2 (X)$ function, $K (x,y)$ a $L^2 (X\times X)$ function. Define $Tf (x)=\int_X K (x,y)f (y)dy$. I need to prove that $||Tf||_2 \leq ||K||_2||f||_2$.

I can bound the left side with
$\int_X |f (y)|^2 \int_X |K (x,y)|^2 dx dy$. But I dont see how to conclude.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is stated correctly? The scaling of what you have written seems amiss to me.

Answer (score 2):

By Minkowsy integral inequality

$$\Big(\int_X\Big(\int_X K(x,y)f(y)dy \Big)^2dx\Big)^\frac{1}{2}\le\int_X\Big(\int_X K(x,y)^2f(y)^2dx \Big)^\frac{1}{2}dy\Big)=\int_Xf(y)\Big(\int_X K(x,y)^2dx \Big)^\frac{1}{2}dy\Big)$$
by Holder
$$\int_Xf(y)\Big(\int_X K(x,y)^2dx \Big)^\frac{1}{2}dy\Big)\le\Big(\int_Xf(y)^2\Big)^\frac{1}{2}\Big(\int_X\int_X K(x,y)^2dx dy\Big)^\frac{1}{2}$$
that is the desired inequality.

Comment: You changed the order from dy dx to dx dy. I don't see why you can do that with all the powers floating around.

Comment: That is precisely what Minkowsky integral inequality states. Indeed it's quite a powerful result.

Comment: Apparently your references use different nomenclature; I've only ever heard the Minkowski inequality used to refer to the triangle inequality for $L^p$ spaces (or sometimes the convexity step that is used in the proof). What you are using here appears to be somewhat different.

Comment: See here : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality#Minkowski.27s_integral_inequality.